# How to fix holes in Plot3D

Tags: plotting

I have a function that produces something like that:

```
10^-8 (5.986357754778547 Sin[2 Pi x] Sin[7 Pi y] - 
        3.9800423510468493 Sin[4 Pi x] Sin[7 Pi y])
```

Then I tried to plot it:

```
Plot3D[10^-8 (5.986357754778547 Sin[2 Pi x] Sin[7 Pi y] - 
    3.9800423510468493 Sin[4 Pi x] Sin[7 Pi y])
 , {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

But there are some unexpected holes:[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `PlotRange -> All`:

```
Plot3D[10^-8 (5.986357754778547 Sin[2 Pi x] Sin[7 Pi y] - 
    3.9800423510468493 Sin[4 Pi x] Sin[7 Pi y]), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]